# Is a trig function with a constant in its parenthesis a constant?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

For example: Is $\sin(8)$ a constant? I want to know because my professor differentiated it to $0$ and that was the explanation he gave. Thanks

Comment: Yes it's a constant. It doesn't change when you change $x$; it has a set value.

Comment: The number you gave is the sine of the angle with measure 8 radians ≈ 458º, so its value is about 0.9894.  It is just a number, so it has zero "instantaneous rate of change".  (In a sense, we are talking about the "constant function" $ \ y = \sin 8 \ , $ and going through the "limit definition" process for derivatives shows that it has the zero derivative function.)

Comment: @Shahar I think this isn't quite the right explanation. $x$ can't be changed since you're looking at only one specific value. You can't change a fixed number.

Comment: @CameronWilliams That's what I said.

Comment: An additional way of seeing this is to ask yourself: "is Euler's constant a constant"?  And follow with: "If you add constants are they constants? What about $e^{-1}$ or $e$ to any other constant power?"  Now, let's assume the $8$ in the $\sin(8)$ is radians for convenience here.  $\sin(8) = \frac{e^{\imath 8} - e^{-\imath 8}}{2 \imath}$.  So now, maybe you can see the trig function as not just some function but built from operations you know keep constants constant.  It's still good to understand that without free variables an expression won't change, but maybe this helps?

Answer (score 2):

Given any function $f(x)$ and a fixed value $x=x_1$, $f(x_1)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

This is most definitely the case. It's true for *any* function not only trigonometric functions. When you plug a value into a function, you get one (and only one!) value, meaning it is a constant at that point. Think about the graph of your function. When you look at a specific value for the input variable (say $x=8$), the graph tells you what your function value is for that specific value.

Answer (score 1):

Sin(8) is just a fancy way to write a fancy number. It is certainly constant.

If you take the derivative of e^2, 2π, or (42)², it is the same story. They are just numbers, it doesn't matter what symbols we used to write them.

Comment: I was always under the impression that sin/cos/etc were like numbers in of themselves. Meaning, they had an inherent value. That's the way it seems after verifying trig identities and using trig in calculus anyways. You make it sound as if they are operations though.

Comment: They are unary operations, not numbers themselves. That there are identities among them does not mean they are numbers. Functions are mathematical objects in their own right, and we may study their interactions, even though they are not numbers.

Comment: @chopperdrawlion4 Note that trigonometric functions are functions. I.e., they take in the value of some real number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and give out the value $y\in\mathbb{R}$. However, for a function, how do we know what value is given? Is there a specific way to determine that? Yes. That is the expression of the function. For example, $f(x)=x-1$ takes any real number and gives as output another real number.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have two functions $f(x)=\sin{x}$ and $g(x)=8$, which the second is constant, then $$f(g(x))=\sin{8}$$
At that point you can see that $f(g(x))$ don't vary with $x$ then is constant.
Other way to see it is via the chain rule:
$$(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
What, for your case is:
$$(f(g(x)))'=\cos(8)(8)'=cos(8)0=0$$
Then the function $f(g(x))=\sin{8}$ is constant for all $x$.

Hope it helps you to understand